# Meta box values are displayed on Custom Fields list. Is it possible to hide them?

Tags: custom-field, metabox, post-meta

I have multiple meta boxes for my Custom Post Type posts.

I want my users to add new fields using [Custom Fields](http://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields). The problem is - Custom Fields display all the garbage from my metaboxes and it might be very confusing for users.

Here's a screenshot, the two first fields were added by an user and the rest comes from the theme itself (there are metaboxes above this "Custom Fields" box which use / reset these fields on post save). How do I hide them?

[image]

Comment: I, personally dislike WordPress' default Custom Field design. Why not incorporate a good plugin like "Advanced Custom Fields" (ACF) or "Extra Fields"? With my ACF experience I can say, you can choose what CFs will be visible and in that post type what other meta boxes will be visible too.

Comment: I know, but I don't want to use any plugins, this default Custom Field design is good enough and have all the features I need, the only problem is I have absolutely no idea how to work this issue out... Also I just want to know the answer (and I hope there is one, if not then Custom Fields seem useless to me), and I wouldn't learn anything new using plugin :) Thanks a lot anyway!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prefix all meta data keys used in meta boxes with an underscore, this will hide them automatically from the built in Custom Fields interface.

So instead of:

```
themeprefix_source
```

Use:

```
_themeprefix_source
```

Comment: Neat! Is this somewhere in documentation?